# Missing Item ID

Tags: personalization

I have in my local machine a clean installation of Sitecore 8.1. I did the upgrade to Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161221. Now I'm trying to do a component personalization, and after I click on "Personalization" this error is displayed:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   There is no item with ID 74A0D116-A2ED-41A6-840B-847F679E25D1
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

I tried to search for the ID from the error message in the master and web databases, but couldn't find an item with that ID.

Does anyone have any idea how can I find or fix this ID to delete the Item? Thanks.

Comment: by any chance this ID refers to a rendering/sublayout which got deleted as part of the upgrade? you are not seeing an unknown rendering message on content editor are you?

Comment: that is the id of the Ruleset Exposure item:
[/sitecore/system/Settings/Content Testing/Report Queries/Ruleset Exposure].
I'm guessing that the upgrade wasn't quite right and blew away some items? If that's the case you'll need to start over. Fortunately SIM makes that easy :)